# How would you plot f(x1) * g(x2) against x1*x2?

Tags: probability-distributions

I have two graphs **f(x)** and **g(x)** which exist on the same infinite domain. I want to create a graph **h(x)** that plots **f(x) * g(x)** against **x1 * x2** and I'm not sure how.

To be precise, I want to take two univariate Gaussian distributions and graph them as one distribution where $\mu$ is equal to or close (rightward skewed) to $\mu_1 + \mu_2$.

Comment: I'd make $x_1=x$, $x_2=y$ and $f(x_1)g(x_2)=z$. Then I can make a surface plot or a color plot. You need to clarify what you want regarding the distribution though. You want to plot the joint probability density?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what I want... I'm trying to calculate the area of a square where both dimensions are described as normal distributions. I'm not sure if my approach is right, but I'll try joint probability density, thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1112866/product-of-two-gaussian-pdfs-is-a-gaussian-pdf-but-product-of-two-gaussian-vari/2520814) then.